# Keep Trailing zeros when Parsing Json using jayway JsonPath

Tags: java, json, jsonpath, jayway

I am using jayway json-path - 2.4.0 to parse Json.  When Parsing json, if the json contains any double value, its truncating the trailing zeros. For Example, I have a Json String like below.

> {"name" : "Sparker" , "value": 60.10}

And my Code:

```
package com.test;

import com.jayway.jsonpath.DocumentContext;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class TestClas {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String value = "{\"name\" : \"Sparker\" , \"value\": 60.10}";
    DocumentContext docCtx = JsonPath.parse(value);
    JsonPath jsonPath = JsonPath.compile("$.value");
    Object result = docCtx.read(jsonPath);
    System.out.println(result);
  }
}
```

And it just prints 60.1, but I need 60.10. How to get the result without truncating trailing zeros.

Answer (score 1):

You are not specifying a type - you are just using `Object` - so it is choosing `Double` automatically. `Double` has no concept of trailing zeros: that is an aspect of how a number is *displayed*.

See [What is Returned When?](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#what-is-returned-when)

Comment: I want to make my class generic. I want to parse different Json paths which returns different objects (String, Int, List, Map etc). Thats why used object.

Comment: Even with adding a type the first parsing is double.